# I want to remove top menu bar for a particular website

Tags: layout

I have more than one websites in my store. I want to remove top menu bar for a particular website(Visible in one website and hidden in another).

It's possible to remove for particular store using layout XML file?

Please provide me inputs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add observer to your module.

```
<events>
  <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
    <observers>
      <customtopmenu>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>MyNameSpace_MyModule_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>customtopmenu</method>
      </customtopmenu>
    </observers>
  </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>     
</events>
```

After that,add Observer model class.

```
class MyNameSpace_MyModule_Model_Observer
{

public function customtopmenu($observer)
{

    // Gets the current website id
    $website_id = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();     
    if($website_id == 2) { 
    $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
    $layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate('<remove name="top.menu">');
    $layout->getUpdate()->load();
    $layout->generateXml();
    $layout->generateBlocks();
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

you will use an observer for it.

in your `config.xml` define and use below event to update layout

```
<events>
  <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
    <observers>
      <allproducts>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>newmenu</method>
      </allproducts>
    </observers>
  </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>     
</events>
```

you must create `Observer.php` in the Model

```
class NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Observer
{

public function newMenu($observer)
{

    // Gets the current store's id
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

    if($storeId == 2) { // check for your store id which you don't need to display

    $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

    // remove all the blocks you don't want
    $layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate('<remove name="catalog.topnav">'); // it may be differ as per your theme just check for exact name in your theme

    // load layout updates by specified handles
    $layout->getUpdate()->load();

    // generate xml from collected text updates
    $layout->generateXml();

    // generate blocks from xml layout
    $layout->generateBlocks();

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Didn't test it but `$layout->removeOutputBlock('catalog.topnav');` should also work instead of `$layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate('<remove name="catalog.topnav">');` and will be more flexible.

Comment: @AnnaVölkl,thanks for your comment and share new things, yes you can use it as well.

Comment: @Anna, Great thanks..Your inputs is really appreciable

Comment: @liyakat Raise a flag on that answer it looks like some gambling.

Answer (score 0):

You might have done it by XML (either in custom module's layout xml or your theme's local.xml)

```
<STORE_mystore> <!-- put your exact store code in place of 'mystore' -->
    <remove name="catalog.topnav"/>
</STORE_mystore>
```

Or maybe less 'aggressive' method:

```
<STORE_mystore>
    <reference name="topMenu">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <name>catalog.topnav</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
</STORE_mystore>
```

Of course, your `name`s may differ, depending on your theme. I took these from `rwd_default`.

**EDIT**

Code example from my comment, to make it readable:

```
<STORE_tech>
    <reference name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo>
                <label>Home</label>
                <title>Home</title>
                <link>{{baseUrl}}</link>
            </crumbInfo>
        </action>
    </reference>
</STORE_tech>
```

Comment: I have tried to put the handle of <STORE_code> for placing the breadcrums in the particular store,but it doesn't seems to be working.
Can you please check ?
I am putting my layout XML code here.

Comment: <STORE_tech>
  <customer_account_index>
   <reference name="breadcrumbs">
    <action method="addCrumb">
     <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
     <crumbInfo>
      <label>Home</label>
      <title>Home</title>
      <link>{{baseUrl}}</link>
     </crumbInfo>
    </action>    
   </reference>
  </customer_account_index>
    </STORE_tech>

Comment: Hi Dmakabr, please help me out.. your inputs is really appreciable.

Comment: Hi. It seems that you are nesting handles. I mean, you should use, for example: (check update in my answer).Although it would add breadcrumb for the whole store, not only customer account page and I don't know if that's desired effect

Answer (score 0):

To remove catalog Menu in storefront using default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="catalog.topnav" remove="true" />
```